# setting multiple request parameter Optional

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am stuck in big problem i want to ignore some attributes of object but do not know how to skip multiple attributes from same request object

here is my code

**TestRequestInfo.java**

```
public class TestRequestInfo extends BaseFilter {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

**BaseFilter.java**

```
public class BaseFilter {

    private PagingInfo paging;

    public PagingInfo getPaging() {
        return paging;
    }
    public void setPaging(PagingInfo paging) {
        this.paging = paging;
    }


}
```

**PagingInfo.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "paging")
    public class PagingInfo {
        private Integer totalNumOfRows;
        private Integer minRowNumber;
        private Integer maxRowNumber;

        public PagingInfo() {
            super();
        }

        public PagingInfo(Integer totalNumOfRows, Integer maxRowNumber, Integer minRowNumber) {
            super();
            this.totalNumOfRows = totalNumOfRows;
            this.maxRowNumber = maxRowNumber;
            this.minRowNumber = minRowNumber;
        }

        public PagingInfo(Integer maxRowNumber, Integer minRowNumber) {
            super();
            this.maxRowNumber = maxRowNumber;
            this.minRowNumber = minRowNumber;
        }
        public Integer getTotalNumOfRows() {
            return totalNumOfRows;
        }
        public void setTotalNumOfRows(Integer totalNumOfRows) {
            this.totalNumOfRows = totalNumOfRows;
        }

        public Integer getMinRowNumber() {
            return minRowNumber;
        }

        public void setMinRowNumber(Integer minRowNumber) {
            this.minRowNumber = minRowNumber;
        }

        public Integer getMaxRowNumber() {
            return maxRowNumber;
        }

        public void setMaxRowNumber(Integer maxRowNumber) {
            this.maxRowNumber = maxRowNumber;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "/testList"} , method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public @ResponseBody String testList(HttpServletRequest request, TestRequestInfo testRequestInfo)
        {
        ....
        ....
        }
```

request i made

```
http://example/abc/testList?id=&paging.maxRowNumber=&paging.minRowNumber=
```

on blank attribute request it made it bad request and gives `ERROR 400` and if i populate these parameters, it gives proper response.

`@RequestParam(value = "i", required=false)` works only for singly entity how can i make `minRowNumber` and `maxRowNumber` optional?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code and my test.

```
> http://localhost:8080/FileUpload/testList.htm?id=1&paging.maxRowNumber=1&paging.minRowNumber=1
> TestRequestInfo [id=1, getPaging()=PagingInfo [totalNumOfRows=null,
> minRowNumber=1, maxRowNumber=1]]
> 
> http://localhost:8080/FileUpload/testList.htm?id=1&paging.maxRowNumber=1&paging.minRowNumber=
> TestRequestInfo [id=1, getPaging()=PagingInfo [totalNumOfRows=null,
> minRowNumber=null, maxRowNumber=1]]
> 
> http://localhost:8080/FileUpload/testList.htm?id=1&paging.maxRowNumber=&paging.minRowNumber=
> TestRequestInfo [id=1, getPaging()=PagingInfo [totalNumOfRows=null,
> minRowNumber=null, maxRowNumber=null]]



 @RequestMapping(value = { "/testList"} , method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody String testList(HttpServletRequest request, TestRequestInfo testRequestInfo)
 {

    System.out.println(testRequestInfo);
    return "ss";
 }
```

My spring config

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

As you can see code is completely functional, it seems that problem could be the url-pattern that you are using.

Check that you are using

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are right code is functional, i was receiving exception internally from another function which results in Bad request :)